# In Objective-C, do we have to use self.var or just var to reference a property of self?

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I add a property to the ViewController

```
@property (strong, atomic) UIView *smallBox;
```

and synthesize it in the `.m` file, the variable can actually be referenced just by `smallBox` inside of any instance methods.

But then, `self.view` cannot be replaced by `view`, even though `view` is defined as a property of UIViewController too.  Why the difference and what is the rule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`self.view` and `view`/`_view` are not the same thing. Depending on how you create your instance variables, `view` or `_view` refer to the actual object instance variable. It is dangerous to access this directly, and you should only do so in `init`, `dealloc` or in accessors. Everywhere else, you should use `self.view`.

`self.view` is exactly the same as `[self view]`, which passes the message "view" to the object "self" an returns the result. By default, when an object receives a message, it executes the method with that name, and the default implementation of `view` will return the value of the related instance variable (either `view` or `_view`).

In older versions of Xcode, `@synthesize view` would create an instance variable called `view`. In the latest versions of Xcode, declaring a property `view` will will automatically create an instance variable called `_view` in many cases, even without `@synthesize`. This change makes it easier to notice when you are accessing the ivar directly.

In short:

- except in `init`, `dealloc` and the `view` accessors (if you custom write them), always use `self.view`.
- In those methods, you should refer to it as `_view`.
- If you are writing for the latest Xcode, do not include `@synthesize` at all. If you are writing for a slightly older Xcode, use `@synthesize view=_view;`
- `self.view` does not mean "the value of the instance variable." It means "the result of passing the message 'view'" which is generally implemented as returning the instance variable.

Comment: I wouldn't describe accessing the ivar directly as "dangerous", especially if you're using ARC or they are `assign` variables.

Comment: @JesseRusak what if it is atomic?

Comment: I cannot print out `_view`... can only print out `self.view`, so maybe it is the reason of `@package` as mentioned by Jesse...  By the way, if I print out in the debugger `_smallBox` or `self.smallBox`, they print out the same thing, but if I do `p smallBox`, then it prints out `(UIView *(*)()) $0 = 0x0002b929 (TryLayoutAndResize-[ViewController smallBox] + 1 at ViewController.h:13)`... maybe it is the "getter method"?  but `p setSmallBox` or `p setSmallBox:` won't print out similar things

Comment: Minor clarification: In the latest versions of Xcode, if you omit the `@synthesize`, it will automatically synthesize the ivar with the leading underscore. But if you do have a `@synthesize` statement without providing the ivar name, the default ivar name will _not_ have the underscore. So, if you do explicitly declare the `@synthesize` statement, it's prudent to also specify a unique ivar name (since it won't happen automatically), for the reasons you outline.

Comment: Why does `init`, `dealloc`, and `view` getter have to use `_view` instead of `self.view`?  Is it because `view` getter has the mechanism of "create it if not already exist"?  If it is out own code that doesn't use this "create it if not already exist" mechanism, then we can use either `_data` or `self.data` in any method?  (because `self.data` returns `_data` anyway)

Comment: @JesseRusak, while the likelihood of crash has reduced, it is still common for there to be custom behaviors in accessors including lazy loading, locking, and KVO notifications (which are not obvious in the code). Bypassing your accessors as habit, even in ARC, can and does lead to very subtle bugs and so is still dangerous.

Comment: @動靜能量, The getter and setter *must* use the ivar directly. Otherwise, it is a loop. `init` and `dealloc` *should* use the ivar directly to explicitly and intentionally avoid the kinds of side-effects from custom setters that I mentioned to Jesse. In `dealloc` in particular, you usually want to avoid generating KVO notifications. In `init` and `dealloc`, you need to be concerned about subclasses who may override the accessors, even if you have not in the current class. There is no equivalent of `final` in ObjC, so you should assume you may be subclassed.

Comment: There are many senior programmers around who do not understand the use of ivars, properties, and the difference in using them in reference to memory management. I strongly advise to profile your code for memory leaks and zombies, then when you can prove to the senior dinosaurs that what they are doing is incorrect, only then will they believe in evolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the `view` member directly because it's declared as `@package` visibility in `UIViewController`. This prevents your code from accessing it. (Normally, you wouldn't want to access instance variables of your superclasses directly anyway.)

For your class's own properties, you can access the instance variable directly, but you need to be aware of the memory management implications of this. (As well, as Rob points out, as any other behaviours you're side-stepping by avoiding the accessor.)

Comment: Not just memory management. You must be aware of possible side effects from accessors (including accessors in subclasses), and particularly the impact on KVO. Direct ivar access breaks KVO, so you should not do it except in specific instances where you *mean* to break KVO (such as in `dealloc`).

Answer (score 0):

Apple defined properties usually contain an underscore before their name, so when you use `self.view`, it is actually getting the instance variable `_view` from the object. You cannot use `_view` in code, as it will cause a linker error on compiling, but Xcode will still highlight it for you. Another way of accessing the instance variable for `self.view` is by `self->_view`, but again, this causes a linker error. The reason for these linker errors is because the compiled libraries do not contain the symbols for `_view`; even if its declaration can be found in `UIViewController.h`.

Comment: If I also use `@synthesize smallBox=_smallBox;`, then I cannot use `smallBox` but have to use `self.smallBox`...  but why and what is the rule?  If I use `@synthesize smallBox=_smallBox;` doesn't that just mean for the instance variable for this property, I want it specifically to be `_smallBox` but why does it matter at all if it is `_foo` or `_smallBox`?

Comment: But then if I use `@synthesize smallBox=smallBox;`, then I can now use `smallBox`, so it looks like the default is: the instance variable name is the same as the getter and setter if nothing is specified as in `@synthesize smallBox;`.  So in this form, is it not a good practice to use `smallBox` or it doesn't really matter?  What if it is atomic, then it matters?   (because no lock is acquired or released.  can't it be a bug that's hard to catch that way?)

Comment: @動靜能量: Synthesizing with an underscore in front ensures you don't confuse the property with the underlying ivar (this is a source of common errors).

Comment: then maybe it can make sense in future versions of Objective-C to default it that way?  (use `_smallBox` as the ivar)

Comment: @動靜能量, if you omit the `@synthesize` statement altogether, in Xcode 4.4 and higher, it will do precisely that, synthesizing the ivar with the leading underscore to eliminate the confusion.